# How to formulate newcomer questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, asking-questions, new-users

I'm not trying to whine but trying to learn how to phrase questions appropriately for SE.

Not having had any experience with freelancing my questions are going to be more general much like [my first one](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-the-pro-and-cons-of-working-directly-with-a-client-versus-through-a-con).  It got closed with the generic guideline text.  I found the few answers I got so far very constructive and helpful.

Quite a few of the other questions on Freelancing appear to be ones that generate only subjective answer much like my question but surprisingly they aren't closed.  Meaning, I don't see what is so inherently wrong with my question.

All I really wanted was a list (or lists) of things that are good and bad with either option.  What would a better wording for this question be?

Answer (score 3):

Being a newcomer is perfectly fine on a Stack Exchange site; being new to a field of course means you're not an expert, but newcomers can still do some basic research on their own, using Google, to help give them a stronger foundation to create a more powerful question.

The best questions on Stack Exchange are those that are about a real, actual problem you're facing. The best questions are those that contain some details about the problem, enough so that users can provide answers based on facts, references, and specific expertise. The community uses voting as a tool to identify the best answers and move them to the top. This helps future visitors who have the same problem quickly find the answers without having to wade through noise.

But pros and cons questions sometimes tend to encourage users to post simple lists with no explanation. I don't think that will happen on this question, but it's still harder to tailor the answers so that they apply to your specific situation. What's more, every answer will likely be correct, which makes it harder to vote the best information to the top.  See [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) for more details.

**Possible ways to improve the post:**

While your question in your current format may not fit the model, that doesn't mean you don't have some kind of question you could ask. Instead, start by thinking about why you're asking for this list. What specifically are you most worried about in getting started freelancing? If you don't know pros and cons, start by spending 5 minutes Googling them.  The pros and cons are likely already answered elsewhere, and this will lead to a deeper question that will encourage answers with more depth, experience, facts, and references. This not only will help you more, but it will help this site during it's most critical period, the private beta.

Right now, we're essentially architects who are designing a new Stack Exchange Q&A site, and the questions we ask in the next few weeks will determine the tone of the site for years to come. Questions that show we've put thought into them will more likely attract the experts we need to make a viable site.

When this site moves to public beta and is opened up to the world, we want to ensure there's good content that makes people want to contribute more great content. Hope this helps, and good luck with your edits to your question! :)

Answer (score 3):

Questions from beginners like yourself are more than welcome — we love them — but this type of Q&A format excels at addressing *specific* problems you encounter in your day to day work. I can appreciate your desire to ask for "a list of things" to get you started. But **asking for a list of answers you can pick through later isn't how this site is designed.**

Take a look at [**"About Freelancing Stack Exchange"**](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/about) to see how this all works.

Stack Exchange takes a different approach to Q&A; different than most of the forum-chatrooms folks are accustomed to. The Freelancing Stack Exchange is designed to create a definitive cannon of knowledge to answer the types of problems you encounter in your day to day work — practical, specific, answerable questions.

There's nothing *inherently* wrong with your question. It's been asked hundreds of times in every forum on this subject. But we try to forgo such broad, open-ended questions. That is by design. This site focuses instead on those *specific* problems you'll encounter in your day to day work. Describe the situation and explain where you are having difficulties. That way, the users here are not left *guessing* how they can help you… specifically.